# Spaces with back ticks in grouping variable for list-columns with tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Curious if this is a bug in `tibble`, `tidyr`, or `dplyr`? Specifically with the use of list-columns?

For example,

If I want to create a list column (or several) and have a grouping variable, I'd go about like so:

```
library(tidyerse)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest()
```

However, if I have a space in the grouping variable like so I get an error thrown:

```
mtcars %>%
  rename(`cyl Space`=cyl) %>%
  group_by(`cyl Space`) %>%
  nest()

>Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:5: unexpected symbol
>1: cyl Space
        ^
```

Now you can obviously use spaces with back ticks in other applications of group_by():

```
mtcars %>%
  rename(`cyl Space`=cyl) %>%
  group_by(`cyl Space`) %>%
  summarise(dis_mean = mean(disp))
```

I looked around but haven't noticed this problem documented elsewhere.

Any ideas?

Session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)


attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggthemes_3.3.0  lubridate_1.6.0 dplyr_0.5.0     purrr_0.2.2     readr_1.0.0     tidyr_0.6.0     tibble_1.2      ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyverse_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.8      assertthat_0.1   R6_2.2.0         grid_3.3.2       plyr_1.8.4       DBI_0.5-1        gtable_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5    
 [9] scales_0.4.1     stringi_1.1.2    lazyeval_0.2.0   tools_3.3.2      stringr_1.1.0    munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.3-1
```

Comment: I can reproduce with `dplyr_0.5.0      purrr_0.2.2.9000 readr_1.0.0      tidyr_0.6.0      tibble_1.2       ggplot2_2.2.1    tidyverse_1.0.0 `. Even for `tibble(``foo bar`` = 1) %>% 
  group_by(``foo bar``) %>% 
  nest()`

Comment: Good point. Added `sessionInfo` to the original question.

Comment: Adding tidyr tag since the seeming culprit is tidyr::nest.

Comment: I suppose I'll file this as an issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is indeed a bug and has already been filed in `tidyr` (and links contain therein):

https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/244